# Mongoose match by documents created in the last 24 hours and by id

Tags: mongoose

I have been coding an app which is taking all the measurements for the past 24 hours for certain id (sensor). I have all the sensor's data in one collection. Of course I set timestamp for the Model. idStation is the id in the document

```
const getSensorMeasurementForThePastDay = async (id: string) => {

  let measurements = await Data.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $and: [
          { "createdAt": { "$gt": new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) } },
          { idStation: id } 
        ]
      }
    },
  ])
```

I managed to take all the information for the past 24 hours, but not for certain id. Tried different things but I would be grateful if someone gives a hand.

Comment: What's the problem with the query? Also, if you only want to do this stage, you can do it using `find` instead of `aggregate`.

Comment: @J.F. Without the { idStation: id } match is returning all of the documents for the last 24 hours, and with it empty array

Comment: Maybe you have to parse `id` to `ObjectId` because now mongo is matching ObjectId vs String. Try something like `{idStation: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `aggregate()`, and `$gt` have different syntax when used in Aggregation framework. For your use case, you can use `find()`:

```js
let measurements = await Data.find({
  "idStation": id,
  "createdAt": { "$gt": new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) } 
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it was simple but I was thinking of something harder. Still had to make a few changes because of typescript, but it worked!